# Multiple return statements in a PHP function

Tags: php

I have the following PHP function

```
function newUser($username, $password) {
     $checkUsernameAvailablity = check($username);
     if (!$checkUsernameAvailablity)
         {
           return -1;
         } 

         $checkPasswordComplexity = checkpass($password);
         if (!$checkPasswordComplexity)
         {
           return -2
         }

}
```

I would like to know if the username is taken and the password is not complex enough, will PHP stop the function after it returns -1 or will it continue and return -2 also.

Thanks in advance,
RayQuang

Comment: The question is will PHP stop the function after it finished the first return statement or will it continue?

Comment: @RayQuang - If called from within a function, the return()  statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call. return() will also end the execution of an eval() statement or script file. , more - http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: The code also contains an error... `if (!$checkpass)` will never evaluate as true since it's an undefined variable ... you should evaluate `$checkPasswordComplexity `

Comment: Oh sorry about the mistakes, This is not the actual code I just made it up to illustrate the point.

Comment: @RayQuang: just curiuos, why did not you try before ask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` statement returns the value and terminates the execution of the function. If the `return` is hit, no further code is executed in that body.

By the way, not all code paths have return values.

Comment: Be careful there: Unless the script exists, all code paths have return values, just that those values can be null. A blank return returns `NULL` and there is an implicit return at the end of a function that doesn't otherwise have a return call.

Comment: NULL is arguable a value. It means 'no value'. It's just that the result is far more obvious when you actually return something. You then know what to expect. In PHP it may not be a big deal, but I'm used to having implicit return values. In some other, "orthodox" languages, that just wouldn't compile.

Answer (score 6):

When execution reaches a `return` statement, the function will stop and return that value without processing any more of the function.

Answer (score 2):

the design of your function is wrong.

I would return different values when the function ends accordingly.

For multiple returns I would use switch or a properly designed IF statements.

Or better return an associative array.